# React-MaterialUI: Horizontally aligning single tab to right and others to left in App Bar ->Tabs -> Tab

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

In my React application, I have a Navigation bar where in there are multiple Tabs, which are created with the use of Marerial UI's AppBar, Tabs and Tab component (in sequence), as below:

```
function associatedProps(index) {
    return {
        id: `nav-tab-${index}`,
        'aria-controls': `nav-tabpanel-${index}`
    };
}

function LinkTab(props) {
    const history = useHistory();
    const route = props.route;
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <>
        <Tab
            component="a"
            onClick={(event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                history.push(route)
            }}
            {...props}
        />
        </>
    );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        height: theme.navBarHeight
    },
    tabIndicator: {
        backgroundColor: PRIMARY_RED.default
    },
    tabBar: {
      top: '80px'
    }
}));

export default function NavTabs() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.tabBar}>
                <Tabs
                    variant=""
                    classes={{indicator: classes.tabIndicator}}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    aria-label="nav tabs example"
                >
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.MY_LIST} {...associatedProps(0)} />
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.MY_REQUESTS} {...associatedProps(1)} />
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.REPORT} {...associatedProps(2)} />
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now herein this setup I wanted my **REPORT** tab to be aligned right of the App Bar. I do not see any CSS Rule or Prop which in Documentation, which can help me here.

Please suggest how can I achieve this in current setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabs do not provide a property to align a specific item to the start or end. But you can leverage css to achieve your result.

Add a className to the item to be right aligned and define a marginLeft property on it

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        height: theme.navBarHeight
    },
    tabIndicator: {
        backgroundColor: PRIMARY_RED.default
    },
    tabBar: {
      top: '80px'
    },
    rightAlign: {
       marginLeft: 'auto',
    }
}));

export default function NavTabs() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.tabBar}>
                <Tabs
                    variant=""
                    classes={{indicator: classes.tabIndicator}}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    aria-label="nav tabs example"
                >
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.MY_LIST} {...associatedProps(0)} />
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.MY_REQUESTS} {...associatedProps(1)} />
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.REPORT} {...associatedProps(2)} className={classes.rightAlign}/>
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Sample working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cop11)

Comment: Thats Perfect Shubham!! Only change I did wrt your sandbox is :  `<LinkTab alignment={classes.rightAlign} {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.REPORT} {...associatedProps(2)} />` and received it as `<Tab
            component="a"
            onClick={(event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                history.push(route)
            }}
            className={props.label === PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.REPORT.label ? props.alignment: ''}
            {...props}
        />`
Though I was expecting the inbuilt way from Material, somethng like `centered`

Comment: thank you, this is what i am looking for

Answer (score 3):

You should set a class for `Tabs` like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    tabs: {
      '&:last-child': {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '0'
      }
    }
}));

export default function NavTabs() {
    ...
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.tabBar}>
                <Tabs
                    variant=""
                    classes={classes.tabs}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    aria-label="nav tabs example"
                >
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.MY_LIST} {...associatedProps(0)} />
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.MY_REQUESTS} {...associatedProps(1)} />
                    <LinkTab {...PRIMARY_NAVIGATION.REPORT} {...associatedProps(2)} />
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
```